Bentley ProjectWise WSG API: Accessing attributes in a custom schema
I'm looking for help with the Bentley ProjectWise WSG REST API V2.5.
I need a hint how I can access attributes of a file that reside in a custom schema and class. I know how I can find folders and file instances via NavNode as well as the PW_WSG schema and Document class. I can upload and download file instances and access their default attributes via the PW_WSG schema. This includes default metadata like Description, Version etc.
However, most of the attributes I require are stored under a different custom schema. How can I access theses custom attributes that are related to a particular file instance?
I tried retrieving custom attributes via the custom schema and class, using the file_instance_id of my file instance but couldn't get anything. I'd expect to get a JSON with related attributes.
Here's the Python API call I use to download a file and it's attributes in the PW_WSG schema and Document class (which works fine):
endpoint = f"/ws/v2.5/Repositories/{repository_id}/PW_WSG/Document/{file_instance_id}/$file"
response = requests.get(base_url + endpoint, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password), stream=True)

And to upload a file I use (this has properties and relationship to parent folder in the JSON header) - works fine, too:
url = f"/ws/v2.5/Repositories/{repository}/PW_WSG/Document/{file_instance_id}"
response = requests.post(base_url + url, headers=headers, data=file_content, auth=auth, verify=False)

This works fine.
So, my custom attributes are in CustomSchema/CustomClass/Attributes (instead of PW_WSG/Document/Attributes).
So I tried the following to retrieve the custom attributes of my file, using the file_instance_id of my file that has the attributes attached in ProjectWise:
endpoint = f"/ws/v2.5/Repositories/{repository_id}/CustomSchema/CustomClass/{file_instance_id}/$file"
response = requests.get(base_url + endpoint, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password), stream=True)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You can access document environment attributes by endpoint:
endpoint = f"/ws/v2.5/Repositories/{repository_id}/PW_WSG/Environment!poly?$filter=DocumentEnvironment-backward-Document!poly.$id+eq+'{file_instance_id}'

